# How fix error from TorControlError Error reply: Authentication required

Tags: android, kotlin, crashlytics, tor

I check firebase console section crashlytics and some users get crash because of tor.

stack trace from crashlytics:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:614)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:928)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:0)
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:928)
Caused by: net.freehaven.tor.control.TorControlError: Error reply: Authentication required.
    net.freehaven.tor.control.TorControlConnection.sendAndWaitForResponse(TorControlConnection.java:211)
    net.freehaven.tor.control.TorControlConnection.setEvents(TorControlConnection.java:590)
    com._.zlib.ZlibApp$onCreate$1.onServiceConnected(ZlibApp.kt:101)
    android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1771)
    android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1803)
    android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7087)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:0)
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:928)
```

Stacktrace in only one line points to code from my application (ZlibApp.kt:101)

ZlibApp Application class:

```kotlin
//...
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
//...
        bindService(Intent(this, TorService::class.java), object : ServiceConnection {
            override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName?, service: IBinder) {

                val torService: TorService = (service as TorService.LocalBinder).service
                while (torService.torControlConnection == null) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500)
                    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
                Timber.d( "Got Tor control connection, service proxy started")

                //now set our own events
                val events = ArrayList(
                    Arrays.asList(
                        TorControlCommands.EVENT_OR_CONN_STATUS,
                        TorControlCommands.EVENT_CIRCUIT_STATUS,
                        TorControlCommands.EVENT_NOTICE_MSG,
                        TorControlCommands.EVENT_WARN_MSG,
                        TorControlCommands.EVENT_ERR_MSG,
                        TorControlCommands.EVENT_BANDWIDTH_USED,
                        TorControlCommands.EVENT_NEW_DESC,
                        TorControlCommands.EVENT_ADDRMAP
                    )
                )
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    events.add(TorControlCommands.EVENT_DEBUG_MSG)
                    events.add(TorControlCommands.EVENT_INFO_MSG)
                    TorControlCommands.EVENT_STREAM_STATUS
                }

                val conn = torService.torControlConnection
                conn.setEvents(events)                     // this is 101 line
            }

            override fun onServiceDisconnected(p0: ComponentName?) {
                Timber.d( "Tor service proxy disconnected")
            }

        }, BIND_AUTO_CREATE)

        component = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
    }
```

I can't reproduce this error on my device or emulator, startup application passes normally on my device.

I have zero no idea how to fix this.